# Read binary data from YAML using Symfony2 Yaml::dump()

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have a simple question - how to read binary data from **.yml** with Symfony2?

Problem is that `Yaml::dump()` writes raw binary string into **.yml**, and I can see it there, but trying to read that file produces an error:

> The YAML value does not appear to be valid UTF-8.

How to tell `Yaml::parse()` to accept raw binary data? I've seen solutions with Ruby and C++ here on SO, but nothing on Symfony.

Current workaround is native PHP `bin2hex()` function, but that's an extra action I want to avoid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure you will have to use either `bin2hex` like you are now or something like `base64_encode` to store binary data in YAML.

YAML is sensitive to newlines, indentation etc. I can't imagine this working with binary data.

Comment: What about `!! binary |` notation in Ruby parser? It saves binary alright.

Comment: Link pls? From what I've seen its just implicit base64 encoding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277645/converting-a-yaml-response-w-binary-data-to-utf-8-in-ruby-1-8-7 and https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4657, but I kind of see the point about `Base64`.